# how to include both digits with hyphens in javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

how to include both digits and hyphens in `javascript` pattern. Like in phone number where user can add both digits and hyphens. No matter where is the hyphen.

Comment: yes as in javascript pattern attribute

Comment: Here it is in a tester.
https://regex101.com/r/wZ4uU6/10

For your specific quesiton, the interesting part is the following block.

    [-.\s]?
Which specifies hyphen, dot, or space separating the digit groups, with a "?" optional operator.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to make this is so simple. You can make something like this:

```
 ([0-9\-]+)
```

That means all numbers and hypen no matter where is. You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/eX3yA7/1

Comment: thanks for the answer, one more thing how to include spaces also in this regex no matter how many no matter where.

Comment: means digits, hyphen and blank spaces

Comment: `[\d-]` works as well.

Comment: You can add the space inside like this `([0-9\- ]+)`